# If I keep another webiste's link to my website via comment or foroum based facility then Is it help my site any how?

Tags: web, seo

Say If I keep more number of web links of other sites on my web site then is it going to help my website in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will help the other sites as you will be basically providing backlinks to theirs. Unless they have links going back to your site then you won't see any benefit at your end.

Comment: So why all site providing "Comment facility" in which web-address is required field?That's what i was wondering.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not quite clear about in-bound link and out-bound link.

What you are talking about now is out-bound link, which, according Google's PR, is a vote to other site(The linked site), not yours.

What you need, though, is in-bound link. In plain English, links of your sites on other sites.

Be warned, only putting our links on other sites that share the same themes can be counted as valid links. On top of it, do not tempted into Black Hat  SEO!